# APEX Multiple From in Database.getQueryLocator

Tags: apex, apextestrunresult

I have a class (inherited) that sets the StandardSetController through a Database.getQueryLocator as follows:

```
ApexPages.StandardSetController setCon = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(Database.getQueryLocator(
                          [Select m.Id, m.Total_Count__c, m.Status__c, m.Name From Milestone1_Project__c m where m.status__c = 'Active']));
```

I need to cover this in a test class. But can someone tell me what m does in this query? I don't even know what to look up to understand what m is doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`m` is just an [alias](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_alias.htm). You can use it to shorten a query, as demonstrated here (from the documentation):

```
SELECT count()
FROM Contact c, c.Account a
WHERE a.name = 'MyriadPubs'
```

In your specific case, it doesn't do anything, other than make the query longer than necessary, so you can safely ignore it.

You want to insert `Milestone1_Project__c` records in order to cover this code in your unit tests.

Comment: Thanks! Hmm, that is a problem then because I am but it doesn't seem to be finding them. I will need to do some troubleshooting there.

Comment: @JonathanCrow just an educated guess, you may have forgot to actually insert the records. I know I've done that at least once.